# FontAwesome SVG icons with Vuetify - how to use within v-icon/prepend-icon?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue, can't find the exact answer how to use FA SVG icons in v-icon and prepend-icon.
If i use:

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="dekstop" color="gray"></font-awesome-icon>
```

Icons are displayed, but how i can use FA SVG icons in v-icon and prepend-icon?
Sample:

```
            <v-autocomplete v-model="replUser"
            :items="users" 
            color="accent white--text" 
            label="User"
            prepend-icon="dekstop></i>" // i can use material font icons here, but FA SVG not worked
            >

            </v-autocomplete>
```

my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
// import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import i18n from './i18n'
import {
  library
} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import {
  FontAwesomeIcon
} from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import {
  fas
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon) // Register component globally
library.add(fas) // Include needed icons.

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'faSvg',
})
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use svg icons in `v-icon/prepend-icon`, then you need to access them through `$vuetify.icons` object. Any other text in the `v-icon/prepend-icon` will be interpreted as webfont/css class.

But for use `$vuetify.icons` object you should register custom icons. Example:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { faVuejs } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";

Vue.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon); // Register component globally
library.add(faVuejs); // Include needed icons.

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  icons: {
    vue: {
      component: FontAwesomeIcon,
      props: {
        icon: ["fab", "vuejs"]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And now you can use vue-brand icon:

```
<v-icon>$vuetify.icons.vue</v-icon>
<v-text-field prepend-icon="$vuetify.icons.vue"/>
```

Also, you can use without register via `font-awesome-icon`:

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'vuejs']" />
<v-text-field>
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'vuejs']" slot="prepend"/>
</v-text-field>
```

Out of the box vuetify has a preset of icons [config](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/packages/vuetify/src/components/Vuetify/mixins/icons.ts) that can be associated with SVG:

```
...
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
...
library.add(fas);
...
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: "faSvg"
});
```

But for use it you should call $vuetify.icons again (vuetify just wrap preset as component):

```
<v-icon>$vuetify.icons.warning</v-icon>
```

**Full example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rj5y57rm3q?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.js)**

Answer (score -1):

From `Vuetify` [documention](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons):

> Font Awesome is also supported. Simply use the fa- prefixed icon name.
>   Please note that you still need to include the Font Awesome icons in
>   your project.

Maybe it helps you. But, without your sample code I can't be sure

```
    <v-autocomplete v-model="replUser"
      :items="users" 
      color="accent white--text" 
      label="User"
      prepend-icon="fa-dekstop">
    </v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: This answer does not even consider OP asked for the SVG version.