# Font-awesome SVG icons not working with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vuetify.js

> Why this isn't a duplicate of
>   [FontAwesome SVG icons with Vuetify - how to use within v-icon/prepend-icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207257/fontawesome-svg-icons-with-vuetify-how-to-use-within-v-icon-prepend-icon)
>
> That question shows how to add another icon and output it in your component by manually referencing it, whereas this question
>   refers to the changing of the icons in the prebuilt components of
>   Vuetify to SVG icons without the need to do any manual overriding in
>   your Vue components, like the data-table's paginator.

I'm trying to use the SVG icons of font-awesome in a Vue project with Vuetify, I've followed the guide of installing the SVG font package on the Vuetify installation page here

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#install-font-awesome-svg-icons

By only including the config they specify which is:

```
export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'faSvg',
  },
})
```

Icons simply get displayed as text in components, examples:

Search Icon

[image: search icon]

Footer of a data-table

[image: table footer icons]

The main problem is that it should change the prebuilt component's icons as far as I understand it otherwise you would need to manually specify the components icons each time you use it.

My full Vuetify setup file

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuetify from "vuetify"
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core"
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome"

Vue.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
library.add(fas)

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "faSvg",
  },
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FontAwesome SVG icons with Vuetify - how to use within v-icon/prepend-icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207257/fontawesome-svg-icons-with-vuetify-how-to-use-within-v-icon-prepend-icon)

Comment: @ibra Added an explanation as to why it isn't the same

Answer (score 3):

> try this

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
```

Comment: That works but it doesn't output the icons in SVG format

Answer (score 2):

I had a half success by adding a dom wacher.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { library, dom } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import { far } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons";

library.add(fas, far);

Vue.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon);

dom.watch();
```

dom watcher pulls svg for the icons. But not for the rest components like data-tables etc

```
<v-icon>fa-sign-out-alt</v-icon>
```

For the those icons i had to define every value manually:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#using-custom-icons

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";
import "./fontawesome";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "faSvg",
    values: {
      checkboxOn: "fas fa-check-square",
      checkboxOff: "fas fa-square",
      checkboxIndeterminate: "fas fa-minus-square",
      menu: "fas fa-bars"
    }
  }
});
```

Still I could not get the checkbox working with svg. It won't change dynamicly when I click on it.

At this point I'll revert back to webfonts.

I'd rather use SVGs, so any solution is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As of Vuetify 2.2.2 this is supported natively.

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon) // Register component globally
library.add(fas) // Include needed icons

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'faSvg',
  },
})
```

See [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#install-font-awesome-svg-icons) for details